# Can't perform a new query in Visual Studio against a database

Tags: database, visual-studio

I have successfully created a sample server-based database in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition with settings in Tools>Options>Data Tools>Data Connection under SQL Server Instance Name set to 'SQLEXPRESS'. However, upon performing a new query against the database, it displays this error:

```
Msq 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Recipe'.
```

My query is this:

```
SELECT * FROM Recipe
```

My database is named as "Cookbook" with tables Recipe, Ingredient, RecipeIngredient.

When initiating a query, in the Available Databases drop-down menu, the database I have created isn't listed. Is that possible? For Visual Studio to have created a database but not include it in the Available Databases menu?

But creating a database in SQL Server Management Studio is ok. It's in the Available Databases list.

My assumption is that Visual Studio has created a local database instead of a service-based one.

Anyway I am following this [guy's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1m1Znj9dZA) and encountered this error. Please enlighten me. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to *commit* the DB changes. You should see an *Update* or *Commit* button at the top bar, click it.